# What is limiting the number of active workers in a Gradle build?

Tags: testing, gradle, spock

I am trying to run tests in parallel on my laptop, which has 4 pyhsical and 8 logical CPUs.

```
➜  sysctl -n hw.ncpu
8
➜  sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu
4
```

I would like to run at most 4 tests in parallel.
This is the command that I am running:

`./gradlew remoteChromeTest -Pparallel=4 --continue --max-workers=8`

The `parallel` property goes into `maxParallelForks` of the `Test` task.

Still, Gradle only seems to occupy at most 4 workers concurrently (one of which *seems* to be reserved for the build itself), which coincides with the number of physical CPUs (not sure if that matters).

The output looks like this:

```
> Task :remoteChromeTest
Running tests in parallel using 4 processes.
<============-> 92% EXECUTING [12s]
> :remoteChromeTest > 0 tests completed
> :remoteChromeTest > Executing test spec.Spec1
> IDLE
> :remoteChromeTest > Executing test spec.Spec2
> :remoteChromeTest > Executing test spec.Spec3
```

So, only 3 tests are running in parallel.

What am I missing here? The documentation suggests this could be cranked up beyond the number of actual CPUs. The weird part is that one of the workers shows up as `IDLE`.

I am getting the same behaviour on another machine, which has only 2 physical cores, and there it is limited to two processes, i.e. no parallel execution at all.

Why is one worker `IDLE`?

Answer (score 9):

[--max-workers](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4-rc-1/release-notes.html#new-%E2%80%9Cmax-workers%E2%80%9D-build-setting) is not only for tests execution but also for parallel project execution. In the example, however, you are limiting tests execution parallelism to 4. Try setting [maxParallelForks](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_test_execution) to more than 4 and you will see more parallelism in tests execution. But anyway it will be limited to the minimum between the number of tests and `--max-workers`.

You can also enable parallel project execution by using the [--parallel](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_execution) option. And again, the build parallelism, including the test parallelism, will be limited to `--max-workers`:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = 8
    }
}
```

```
gradle clean build --parallel --max-workers=6
...
<<===========--> 85% EXECUTING [15s]
>> :module-1:test > 4 tests completed
>> :module-2:test > 2 tests completed
>> :module-2:test > Executing test so.Module2Spec3
>> :module-2:test > Executing test so.Module2Spec1
>> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec4
>> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec2
>> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec1
>> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec3
```

```
gradle clean build --parallel --max-workers=12
...
<===========--> 85% EXECUTING [13s]
> :module-1:test > 0 tests completed
> :module-2:test > 0 tests completed
> :module-2:test > Executing test so.Module2Spec1
> :module-2:test > Executing test so.Module2Spec2
> :module-2:test > Executing test so.Module2Spec3
> :module-2:test > Executing test so.Module2Spec4
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec1
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Test2
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec4
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Test3
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Test1
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec3
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Spec2
> :module-1:test > Executing test so.Module1Test4
```

Comment: This did not really answer my question. I know I am limiting to 4 tests, because that's what I want (the system under test cannot handle more at the same time). I wrote that also on my question. But I am wondering, why am I getting only *three* parallel tests, and one `IDLE`. My question is: what is causing the `IDLE` worker?

Comment: @ThomasHirsch have you found an answer for that?

Comment: @DiegoMarinSantos No, and I do not have a way to check on this again right now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there is no executable task left, the rest of tasks are depended on the current running ones, you will see that the status `IDLE` will change after some of in progress tasks are done.